# Dual to compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products, compact-operators

Let $X=\mathcal{K}(c_0,\ell_1)$ be the space of compact operators. What is the dual space $X^*$? Actually do we have $X^*=\mathcal{N}(\ell_1,\ell_{\infty})$?

Comment: Sorry, it should be $X^*=\mathcal{N}(\ell_1,c_0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\ell_1$ has the approximation property, $$\mathcal{K}(c_0, \ell_1)\cong c_0^* \otimes_\varepsilon \ell_1\cong \ell_1 \otimes_\varepsilon  \ell_1,$$
where $\otimes_\varepsilon$ is the injective tensor product. See Corollary 4.13 in Ryan's *[Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MSLUBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=tensor%20products%20of%20banach%20spaces&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM26Xym87QAhXkDcAKHaJFBsQQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=tensor%20products%20of%20banach%20spaces&f=false)* for more details. Proposition 3.22 therein confirms your guess that the dual space is $\mathcal{N}(\ell_1, \ell_\infty)$.

By the way, note that $X$ contains a complemented copy of $\ell_1$ so it has non-separable dual, so in particular, this dual space couldn't be $\mathcal{N}(\ell_1, c_0)$ which is separable.